# Reading list from txt file in iPython notebook

Tags: python, string, file-io, text-files

What is the best way to read a list from a text file in my iPython notebook?

This is what I have now and it is not happy.

The format of my results is a single line in a text file that contains a list of jasons.

```
text_file = open('results.txt', 'r')

lines = text_file.readlines()
```

.

Comment: Why not just use ujson?

Comment: use test_file.read().This will return a string and you can split it based on "}" or any other criteria you want

Comment: For this matter, `pandas` is overkill. Moreover, it is not specific to `ipython`. Hence, I remove the irrelevant tags.

Comment: What's wrong with the [json module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)?

Comment: I am dealing with a sliding window average so thats why I am not using just json.

Comment: this is what a small snippet of the output looks like [{'startDate': 1190934605, 'uniqueness': [0.6458333333333334, 0.8333333333333334, 0.875, 0.8854166666666666, 0.8854166666666666, 0.8854166666666666, 0.8854166666666666]}, {'startDate': 1190934605, 'uniqueness': [0.6736842105263158, 0.8631578947368421, 0.9052631578947369, 0.9157894736842105, 0.9157894736842105, 0.9157894736842105, 0.9157894736842105]}]

Comment: I don't understand what the sliding window stuff has to do with reading your file. What _exactly_ are you trying to do? (avarage of what, etc.)

Comment: different metrics that are changing over time in a person's natural language. someone asked why not just use a json, but order does matter .

Comment: What's the problem with order in json? You use a list, not a hash.